# What does "Enable plane trim" in sculpt brush options panel mean?

Tags: sculpting

There is a "Trim" checkbox on the sculpt brush panel that's labeled "Enable plane trim" in the tooltip, but id does not make any difference as far as I can tell. What does it really do?

[image]

Comment: When you start drawing, you do it in a plane defined by the view you are in and the first concerned vertices hit by the brush. The trim distance defines a limit above which vertices are not affected by the brush (if distance is 0.1 for instance, all vertices which are far from this plane of 0.1 or more won't be changed)

Comment: Thanks, I tried it on a more bumpy mesh and setting the distance to very low value really makes the difference.